# If $\lim u_n =\infty$ and $\lim(u_{n+1} - u_n)=0$ then $\lim (u_{\varphi(n)} -n)=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $(u_n)$ is a real sequence such that $\lim u_n =\infty$ and $\lim(u_{n+1} - u_n)=0$. I want to prove that there exits a strictly increasing map $\varphi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that then $\lim (u_{\varphi(n)} -n)=0$.

I have a proof which is not as lean as I suppose it can be...

Would you have a precise but elegant proof for this simple result?

Comment: What's the general idea of your proof anyway?

Comment: I define $E_n=\{k \in \mathbb N \ ; \ k >\varphi(n-1) \text{ and } u_k >n\}$ and define $\varphi$ by induction using $E_n$.

Comment: Is it correct to write: \begin{align}0&=\lim (u_{n+1}\pm (n+1)-u_n)=\lim (u_{n+1}-(n+1))-\lim (u_{n}-n)+1\\&=\lim (u_{n}-n)-\lim (u_{n}-n)+1\end{align} which implies that $\lim (u_{n}-n)$ can only be equal to $+\infty$? Moreover is there really a sequence $u_n$ that goes to infty, but $u_{n+1}-u_n$ goes to $0$? I am not sure.

Comment: @JimmyR. The sequence of partial sums of the harmonic series fulfills that.

Comment: @Joanpemo Of course, that was elementary...

Comment: @JimmyR. The sequence $u_n=\ln(n)$ fulfill his statement, but $\lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_n-n$ does not exist. Basically, you proved that the limit $\lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} u_n-n$ does not exist. Bellal proved that there will be a subsequence $u_{\phi(n)}$ of the original sequence $u_n$ such that $u_{\phi(n)}-n$ actually exists. By a guess, I suppose that $\lim_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \ln(\lceil \exp(n) \rceil )-n = 0$

Answer (score 2):

First, we have   $\lim_{n \to +\infty } u_{n+1}-u_{n}=0$, then, by   Cesàro lemma, we have $$\lim_{n \to +\infty } \frac{u_{n}}{n}=0.$$ Thus, by your assumptions: $$\exists N\in \mathbb{N},\forall n\ge N,u_{n}\le n\text{ and }\left| u_{n+1}-u_{n} \right|<1.\tag{*}$$

Now, we define, for all  $n\in [N,+\infty [\cap \mathbb{N}$, the set  $$A_{n}=\left\{ k\in [N,+\infty [\cap \mathbb{N} :u_{k}\le n \right\}.$$ $A_{n}$ isn't empty, since, by (*), $n \in A_{n}.$ Also, by your assumptions, we have  $\lim_{n\to +\infty } u_{n}=+\infty$. Hence, there is  $k_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $u_{k}>n$, for all $k \ge k_{0}$. This lets us conclude that $A_{n}$ is finite. Bearing everything in mind, we can define $\varphi: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ in the following way: $$\varphi(n)=\left\lbrace 
\begin{array}{c c}\texttt{max} (A_{n}), & \text{for all } n\in [N,+\infty [\cap \mathbb{N} \\
n, & \text{for all } 0\le n<N
\end{array} \right.$$ Observe that, by (*), $u_{\varphi(n)+1}<u_{\varphi(n)} + 1 \leq n +1$. Hence, by the definition of $\varphi$, $\varphi(n+1)\geq \varphi(n)+1>\varphi(n)$. Thus, $(u_{\varphi(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is subsequence of $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Also, the same reasoning let us state that $u_{\varphi(n)}\le n <u_{\varphi(n)+1}$ for all $n\in [N,+\infty [\cap \mathbb{N}$ , then:  $$\forall n\ge N,0\le n-u_{\varphi(n)}\leqslant u_{\varphi(n)+1}-u_{\varphi(n)}.$$ Finally, by the squeeze theorem for sequences,  $\lim_{n \to +\infty } n-u_{\varphi(n)}=0$.

Comment: The ``same reasoning part'' can be readily proven by noting that if, by absurd, $n \geq u_{\varphi(n)+1}.$ Then, by the definition of $\varphi$ for $n \geq N$, $ \varphi(n) \geq \varphi(n)+1$, which is impossible.

Comment: Perfect, Mr. Bellal

Answer (score 0):

I had this idea, which doesn't seem very complicated.

For any $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ , let $\;\phi(k)\;$ be the first natural number such that $\;u_{\phi(k)}> \max\{k,\,\phi(k-1))\}\;$ , Clearly

$\;\phi(1)<\phi(2)<\ldots\;$ , and thus $\;\left\{u_{\phi(k)}\right\}_{k=1}^\infty\;$ is a subsequence of $\;\left\{u_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\;$ so

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}u_{\phi(k)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\infty$$

But also, by the very definition of $\phi\;$, we have that $\;u_{\phi(n)-1}< n\le u_{\phi(n)}\implies\;$

$$\implies0\le u_{\phi(n)}-n< u_{\phi(n)}-u_{\phi(n)-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and the squeeze theorem solves

Comment: Your $\phi$ might not be stricly increasing. Take for example $u_1=3, u_2=2, u_3=1$ and $u_n=\ln n$ for $n \ge 4$. You have $\phi(1)=3, \phi(2)=2$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thank you very much, corrected. In fact, at first I thought I'd begin by choosing a strictly monotone ascending subsequence of $\;\{u_n\}\;$ and on that I'd construct, but I thought this way would be easier. With your comment I think I fixed that.

Comment: Your statement *But also, by the very definition of $\phi\;$, we have that $\;u_{\phi(n)-1}< n\le u_{\phi(n)} ...$* is erroneous in general.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net As before, could you please give an example? I just can't see it.

Comment: Rather than providing to you the example... I will revert to you the question! How do you prove your statement *But also, by the very definition...* If you try to prove it, you'll find the example you're seeking.

Comment: I'm not seeking anything. Thank you.

Comment: Asking for an example ... Seems to be seeking for something. No?

Comment: Ah, that. It was you who claimed something. Thank you.

Comment: No... You claim something in your answer without a proof! And as for your first claim which was wrong, the second claim without a proof is wrong also.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thank you very much. I'll leave it that way until someone shows me my mistake.

Comment: $u_1=7/4, u_2=5/4, u_3=11/4, u_4=9/4$ and $u_n=\ln n$ for $n \ge 5$ proves that your statement is wrong. Again, I'm looking for a real proof. Not for statements that are not proven.

Comment: Thank you. Changing to strong inequality solves the problem, I believe. In your last example we'd have $\;\phi(1)=2,\,\phi(2)=3\,,\,\phi(3)=4,\,\phi(5)=5,...\;$ . I'm really enjoying and learning from this, hopefully you too. Seeing that you have so many insights in this, I think the best is you post your own proof you said you have. That way we all can learn more. Thank you.